# Adding a User Control to a Webpage

Tags: .net, activex, web-controls

I have a compiled class library containing a user control and I'd like to add it to a webpage. I'm adding an object tag to the html page that looks like:

```
 <OBJECT id="Main" classid="http://localhost/HelloWorld/Hello.World.dll#Hello.World.UserControl"></OBJECT>
```

However, the control isn't being displayed. The DLL makes it to my temp files and I get blank the object box on the webpage. I get an error message in my temporary internet files that looks like:

> ?FusionBindError!name=Hello.World.dll Hello.World.UserControl

I don't know how to debug this any further. I'm wondering if it's a namespacing issue?

[Edit]

The following error ended up in the log:

```
Creating security manager

Microsoft.IE.Manager: Microsoft.IE.Manager: unique id lgth = 42
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: Create SecureFactory() with security information
Microsoft.IE.Manager: Created secure factory
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: Creating instance of the object in the correct domain
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: pUrl = http://localhost/HelloWorld/
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: id = 86474707A31303E2234383E24333E2135330000000
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: link = 
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: licenses = 
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: deployment manifest = 
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: Security options = ZoneEvidence, SiteEvidence
Microsoft.IE.Manager: Url = http://localhost/HelloWorld/
Microsoft.IE.Manager: UrlGetPartW returned 0
Microsoft.IE.Manager: UrlGetPartW returned 80070057
Microsoft.IE.Manager: CodeBase = http://10.248.43.15
Microsoft.IE.Manager: Application = HelloWorld
Microsoft.IE.Manager: Found a codebase
Microsoft.IE.Manager: UrlCanonicalize returned 0
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: URL codeBase: http://localhost/
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: URL application: HelloWorld
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: Locating domain for http://localhost/
Microsoft.IE.IDKey: Created key
Microsoft.IE.Manager: The domain does not exist.
Microsoft.IE.IDKey: Created key
Microsoft.IE.Manager: The domain does not exist.
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: Need to create domain
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: Application base: http://localhost/
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: Private Bin Path: bin
Microsoft.IE.IDKey: Created key
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: Trying to create instance of type http://localhost/HelloWorld/Hello.World.dll#Hello.World.Main
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonManager' threw an exception. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.UIPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripManager.set_Renderer(ToolStripRenderer value)
   at ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonManager.b()
   at ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonManager..cctor()
The action that failed was:
Demand
The type of the first permission that failed was:
System.Security.Permissions.UIPermission
The first permission that failed was:
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.UIPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Window="AllWindows"/>

The demand was for:
<PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet"
version="1">
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.UIPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Window="AllWindows"/>
</PermissionSet>

The granted set of the failing assembly was:
<PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet"
version="1">
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.FileDialogPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Access="Open"/>
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.IsolatedStorageFilePermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Allowed="ApplicationIsolationByUser"
UserQuota="512000"/>
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Flags="Execution"/>
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.UIPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Window="SafeTopLevelWindows"
Clipboard="OwnClipboard"/>
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.SiteIdentityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Site="localhost"/>
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.UrlIdentityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Url="http://localhost/HelloWorld/Hello.World.dll"/>
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.ZoneIdentityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Zone="Internet"/>
<IPermission class="System.Drawing.Printing.PrintingPermission, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
version="1"
Level="SafePrinting"/>
<IPermission class="System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1">
<ConnectAccess>
<URI uri="(http|https)://localhost/*"/>
</ConnectAccess>
</IPermission>
</PermissionSet>

The assembly or AppDomain that failed was:
Hello.World, Version=1.0.3460.18220, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
The method that caused the failure was:
Void InitializeComponent()
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
Internet
The Url of the assembly that failed was:
http://localhost/HelloWorld/Hello.World.dll
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonManager.get_CurrentGlobalPalette()
   at ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.VisualPanel..ctor()
   at ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonPanel..ctor()
   at Hello.World.BottomPanel.InitializeComponent()
   at Hello.World.BottomPanel..ctor()
   at Hello.World.Main.InitializeComponent()
   at Hello.World.Main..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateComInstanceFrom(String assemblyName, String typeName, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateComInstanceFrom(String assemblyFile, String typeName, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateComInstanceFrom(String assemblyFile, String typeName, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm)
   at Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory.CreateInstanceWithSecurity2(Int32 dwFlags, Int32 dwZone, String wszSite, String wszId, String wszConfig, String wszLicenses, String wszDeploymentManifest)
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: LOG exception
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: Creating log entry ?FusionBindError!name=Hello.World.dll Hello.World.Main
Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory: Logging to file C:\Documents and Settings\----\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\F84FN98R\CAMF3O8J.HTM
```

The IEHost Error log file (CAMF308J.HTM) contained:

```
*****   IEHOST Error Log (Monday, 22 June 2009 12:00)   *****



URL:        http://localhost/HelloWorld/Hello.World.dll
Zone:       3
Assembly Name:  Hello.World.dll
Type Name:  Hello.World.Main



----- Thrown Exception -----


System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonManager' threw an exception. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.UIPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripManager.set_Renderer(ToolStripRenderer value)
   at ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonManager.b()
   at ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonManager..cctor()
The action that failed was:
Demand
The type of the first permission that failed was:
System.Security.Permissions.UIPermission
The first permission that failed was:


The demand was for:




The granted set of the failing assembly was:
















The assembly or AppDomain that failed was:
Hello.World, Version=1.0.3460.18220, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
The method that caused the failure was:
Void InitializeComponent()
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
Internet
The Url of the assembly that failed was:
http://localhost/HelloWorld/Hello.World.dll
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonManager.get_CurrentGlobalPalette()
   at ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.VisualPanel..ctor()
   at ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonPanel..ctor()
   at Hello.World.BottomPanel.InitializeComponent()
   at Hello.World.BottomPanel..ctor()
   at Hello.World.Main.InitializeComponent()
   at Hello.World.Main..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateComInstanceFrom(String assemblyName, String typeName, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateComInstanceFrom(String assemblyFile, String typeName, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateComInstanceFrom(String assemblyFile, String typeName, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm)
   at Microsoft.IE.SecureFactory.CreateInstanceWithSecurity2(Int32 dwFlags, Int32 dwZone, String wszSite, String wszId, String wszConfig, String wszLicenses, String wszDeploymentManifest)
```

Comment: I haven't tried creating user controls like this. Does .NET fusion log viewer help at all in debugging the problem?

Comment: I wasn't able to get the Fusion Log viewer to help me out. But I did enable the IEHostLogFile setting in the .NET HKLM. I was able to get output from there. It looks like I'm encountering a permissions error with 3rd party DLL I'm inheriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside that file is a stack trace -- if you post it, I might be able to help.

Also, you need to have full-trust with the site set up in your .NET x.x Configuration control panel (or use CASPOL to set it).

Here's how to debug

1. Use fiddler (google, download, and run).
2. Refresh the page
3. Is the control downloaded? Do you get an HTTP 500 -- if so, turn off "Scripts and Executables" on the directory in IIS --- IIS thinks this is an ISAPI DLL and runs it if you all Executables
4. Do you get a fusion bind (you do) -- what's in it -- should be a stack trace -- did you throw it?  Can you fix?
5. Do you have full-trust set up with the site?

Comment: I followed the instructions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdc263t0(VS.80).aspx to set http://localhost/helloworld/ to full trust. (I tried in a variety of zones after local intranet failed.)

Comment: Also: no http 500 errors. Fiddler is cool, thanks for that. The stack exception is thrown by a 3rd party dll.

Comment: I really think it's a trust thing.  Did you set up .NET 1.1 and .NET 2.0 -- I've seen it fail when both weren't set.  Also, try putting on non-localhost host -- access your host via machine name (give the domain full trust first)

Comment: When you set up fulltrust, it just wants the domain -- i.e. localhost, not http://localhost/helloworld/

Comment: Well. I've set both All_Code Code Groups to FullTrust in both 1.1 and 2.0. That should encompass everything, right? Still nothing. I sent an email to the 3rd party dll company. Hopefully I hear something from them.

Comment: I would have thought -- I'd try a non-localhost domain to be sure.  And you set the domain to just localhost, right?  It should just be the domain, not the URL.  And it needs to match the domain in the URL.

Comment: This turned out to be a fulltrust issue after all. I messed around some more with the .NET Framework configuration utility and just set every possible group to FullTrust and it worked. I must've been setting the wrong code groups before. I don't know. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please note: IE8 disables User Controls in the Internet Zone, so please keep that in mind if you plan to deploy this in a production environment.

Comment: I dislike Microsoft and their subpar engineers.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to contribute to the conversation here?